# How to convert metadata comments into summary comments

Tags: c#, xml-comments, comments

I want to write a wrapper class for the set of existing classes. When I go to the definition of existing class it shows meta-data file with comments like

```
     // Summary:
     //     This is Test comments
```

As I am writing the wrapper class it has mostly same functions & I want to use existing comments in my wrapper class. The problem is that it does not show the comments in documentation style like

```
             /// <summary>
                    /// This is test comment
                    /// </summary>
```

Is there any tool to convert first comment type into second or view the meta-data file with summary comments only?

Atul Sureka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open both files together then you could use [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) to add the XML comments (Ctrl-Shift-D) and then copy/paste the actual comment between the tags that GhostDoc creates for you.  Not quite automatic but shouldnt be too bad.

Comment: The Pro version have API and customized templates written in C# or VB, which may be overkill for this task but that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Bazurbat - It does, it also allows you to comment whole files/classes which is helpful.